# 3 column layout with edge columns as wide as their content?

Tags: css

Could someone please explain how to alter [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/QG98e/) so that it has:

- 3 columns together as wide as the container
- right, left columns as wide as content therein (ie they shall not wrap their inline child elements)
- center column to take up remaining width, wrapping its' content as necessary
- all 3 columns to maintain equal height (i.e. if middle column grows in height due to wrapping of its' content, that content should not spill to under either right or left columns)

  - container can still be as wide as the parent element

**fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/QG98e/ - tried using floats but middle column's content expectedly spills over, flowing around right/left columns:

**Markup from the above fiddle**

HTML:

```
<p>other content above</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <button>foo</button>
    <button>bar</button>
  </div>

  <div id="center">

    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <a href="#">curly</a>, <a href="#">moe</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>other content below</p>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    clear: both;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask for us to give you code. You should try it yourself. When and if you have difficulty, ask a specific question about where you're having trouble.

Comment: @dzny - I did try; edit with Plunker forthcoming... Looking forward to your reply thereafter

Comment: I've added a working demo (fiddle) and cited code. please remove 'on hold' designation. BTW 'asking us to recommend or find a tool' as reason to put this q on hold makes no sense, as I am not asking for a tool.

Answer (score -1):

```
  #container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    height: 100px;/*define you*/
    width: 100%;
  }
#left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: inherit;
    left: 0;
}
#center{
    position: absolute;
    width: 56%;
    height: inherit;
    left: 20%;
}
#right{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: inherit;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but the above approach doesn't work since it requires pre-defining column widths - which is what I'd like to avoid